# When and how did Linus Torvalds join the Linux Foundation?

Tags: linux-kernel, history

Wikipedia says the Linux Foundation was a merger between Open Source Development Labs and the Free Standards Group, so Linus doesn't seem involved in the founding of the foundation itself.

When and how did Linus join the Linux Foundation? More broadly, what's his relationship to the Linux Foundation? Do they simply sponsor his work or is he an official employee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [his Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds#Linux), he moved to Open Source Development Labs around June 2003, and when they merged with the Free Standards Group [in 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Standards_Group) to form the Linux Foundation, he became part of the Foundation as a consequence of the merger.

In the LF's [2016 tax filing](https://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/organizations/460503801/201723189349305852/IRS990), he's described (on p.8) as a "key employee", with the job title "Fellow".